# Como unir dois PDFs em base64 em um único

Tags: c#, pdf, concatenação-de-string, base64

Tenho o seguinte cenário:

Recebo dois arquivos codificados como base64, cada qual representa um pdf. Preciso ler esses arquivos e transformá-los num único arquivo codificado como base64.

Exemplo de entrada:

PDF1 = base64 SGVsbG8=

PDF2 = base64 V29ybGQ=

Saída esperada:

PDF3 que represente a união do PDF1 e PDF2 em base64

Eu tentei utilizar o pacote `PdfHandler`, mas não estou conseguindo usar no VS Code, segue o que tentei:

```
    public static class PdfHandler
    {
        public static string MergeBase64PdfFiles(IEnumerable<string> base64Files)
        {
            if (base64Files.Count() == 0)
                return null;
    
                if (base64Files.Count() == 1)
                    return base64Files.First();
    
                using (var pdfFinal = new PdfDocument())
                {
                    foreach(var base64File in base64Files)
                        using (PdfDocument pdf = Base64ToStream(base64File))
                            CopyPages(pdf, pdfFinal);
    
                    return PdfDocumentToBase64(pdfFinal);
                }
            }
    
            static PdfDocument Base64ToStream(string base64)
            {
                using(var stream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64)))
                    return PdfReader.Open(stream, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
            }
    
            static string PdfDocumentToBase64(PdfDocument pdf)
            {
                using (var sm = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    pdf.Save(sm);
                    var bytes = sm.ToArray();
                    return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
                }
            }
    
            static void CopyPages(PdfDocument from, PdfDocument to)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < from.PageCount; i++)
                    to.AddPage(from.Pages[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Já existe um pacote pra isso?

Comment: O enunciado da pergunta fala em emendar duas strings, enquanto o corpo fala em emendar dois PDFs. Estou confuso :)

Comment: Sim @epx, no enunciado os dois pdfs estão convertidos em string base64. O que preciso é unir os pdfs e mante-los em string base 64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que a bibioteca que você esteja usando seja complicada... Recomendo o uso da [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

O processo que eu faria seria o seguinte:

- Ler o documento em memoria

```
static PdfDocument Base64ToStream(string base64)
{
    using(var stream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64)))
    return PdfReader.Open(stream, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
}
```

- Unir as paginas dos pdfs:

```
using (PdfDocument one = Base64ToStream(b64pdf1))
using (PdfDocument two = Base64ToStream(b64pdf2))
using (PdfDocument outPdf = new PdfDocument())
{                
    CopyPages(one, outPdf);
    CopyPages(two, outPdf);

    Console.WriteLine(PdfDocumentToBase64(outPdf))
}

void CopyPages(PdfDocument from, PdfDocument to)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < from.PageCount; i++)
    {
        to.AddPage(from.Pages[i]);
    }
}
```

- E então converter o Pdf para base64:

```
static string PdfDocumentToBase64(PdfDocument pdf)
{
   using (var sm = new MemoryStream())
    {
      pdf.SaveToStream(sm);
      var bytes = sm.ToArray();
      return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Veja se na sua versão da biblioteca tem o método SaveToStream, é para resolver.

```
static string PdfDocumentToBase64(PdfDocument pdf)
{
   using (var sm = new MemoryStream())
    {
      pdf.SaveToStream(sm);
      var bytes = sm.ToArray();
      return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    }
}
```

referência: https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.PDF/Spire.PDF-Program-Guide/Document-Operation/Save-PDF-file-to-Stream-and-Load-PDF-file-from-Stream-in-C-.NET.html

Answer (score -3):

```
string.Join("", listaDeStrings);
```